# Why don't this macro work for all cells in range?

Tags: excel, vba

The following Excel VBA code was recorded as Macro. It works well for one cell but not for an entire range of cells. Any ideas why? or tips on how to avoid this situation?

```
Sub IDNEW()
' IDNEW Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""*****""&RIGHT(RC[-10],4)"
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like all of your code boils down to `ActiveCell.Value = """*****""" & RIGHT(ActiveCell.Value, 4)`. Please clarify how the range fits into this story.

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008. I want to pick a cell, or more, with nine-digits number\s in it, and the macro will return it as stated in this line. For example, 123456789 >> *****6789.

Comment: Try:
`ActiveCell.Value ="*****" & Right$(ActiveCell.Value,4)`

Comment: @RedHare Thanks. It still seems to work only on the first cell in the range. What I want is that it will work for all selected cells.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that is for all cells in selection but @taller had it right see his answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub IDNEW()
    Dim c As Range
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        For Each c In Selection.Cells
            c.Value = "*****" & Right(c, 4)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Modify Text Using a Formula With `Worksheet.Evaluate` (in *VBA*)

```vb
Sub IDNEW()
' IDNEW Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Selection
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    
    Dim arg As Range
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        arg.Value = ws.Evaluate( _
            "IFERROR(""*****""&RIGHT(" & arg.Address & ",4),"""")")
    Next arg
    
End Sub
```